# Kibana import not working when Vega code is included and exported via API

Tags: kibana, vega

I have been exporting / importing dashboards in kibana between different environments.
No problems when manually exporting and importing as .ndjson but when I use the API
with curl command to automate the process, all dashboards are imported normally except the ones
that use Vega visualizations. Vega is formatted in JSON and I can't see that the problem could be.

The only useful error that I have when Vega code is reached is:
`command not found`

Anyone had any experience with this?